# Association between Hamiltonian and Eulerian graphs

Tags: graph-theory

I have a question, and also an answer which I assume, is correct, but would like to ask, if some of you could elaborate, and add validity to the provided claim or develop a discussion.

I did not find this question, nor the answer anywhere.

**Question:**

Is there any formal association or fundamental relationship, (as in some kind of theorem etc.) between Hamiltonian graphs and Eulerian graphs?

**My answer:**

No such thing exist. Simple proof is, that finding a Hamiltonian path in a graph  is NP-hard problem, and finding Eulerian path is not a NP-hard problem. Or in other words: If this statement is indeed true, finding the Eulerian path should also be NP-hard problem, which we know is not.

Comment: "...finding the Eulerian path should also be NP-hard problem, which we know is not." implies $P \neq NP$ (which is not yet proved.)

Comment: Finding Eulerian path is not NP-hard.That is completely true.

Comment: Do we agree EULERIAN PATH is in $P$?  If $P=NP$, then $P=NP$-complete, and so every $P$ problem would be $NP$-hard.  Therefore, if there exists a $P$ problem outside of $NP$-hard (as you're asserting), we must have $P \neq NP$.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument shows that you cannot interpret every Hamiltonian path problem as an Eulerian path problem.

However, your argument does not stop you from interpreting every Eulerian path problem as a Hamiltonian path problem which is both actually possible (by looking at the line graph) and pretty useless (it just shows that for an NP-hard problem there can be subclasses that are not NP-hard, but that is hardly surprising).

Whether this changes your answer depends on your definition of "formal association".

Comment: Thank you for elaborating.Maybe I've expressed myself a little bit awkward. I should have emphasized that we should focus on finding the answer and not so much on the interpretation of my solution itself. Thank you once again.